# Java Web Service error: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws, wsimport

I have a problem creating and connecting a Java client to a running Web Service.

I use the following code:

```
Service myService  = null;
URL wsdlLocation = new URL("http://myservice?wsdl");
QName serviceName = new QName(wsdlLocation, "MyService");
Service myService = new Service(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
```

where the Service class was created with the following command:

```
wsimport -d gen -keep http://myservice?wsdl
```

I've also tried with a client generated by Apache cxf 2.4's wsdl2java, but got the same result.

(I've changed the WSDL location and Service class name only for this post, in the code I use the original ones.)

But I get an exception when I call the Web Service deployed on the appserver, when creating the service with the new Service() command.
But: I've tested the wsdl location with SOAP UI and it works perfectly.
Also, I've created a Mock Service using Soap UI and my Java client could connect to it, call it and get the results back.
The problem appears when I want' to call the web service running on the appserver.

Stacktrace:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:149)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:98)
        at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:76)
        at MyService.<init>(MyService.java:42)
        at mypackage.createService(AClass.java:288)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:100)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:199)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:147)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col,system-id]: [1,0,"http://myservice?wsdl"]
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:256)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:205)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:98)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col,system-id]: [1,0,"http://myservice?wsdl"]
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF(StreamScanner.java:677)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleEOF(BasicStreamReader.java:2139)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2045)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1134)
        at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:1248)
        at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:1142)
        at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.read(StaxUtils.java:1069)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:247)
        ... 16 more
```

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Can you share your WSDL? Are you using rpc binding?

Comment: did you solve this problem? I'm getting the same error...

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm getting the same error...

Comment: Unfortunately i do not remember, nor access the code. I am so sorry, not to post a followup... But I 50% sure the problem was with the ?wsdl part missing of the url (or maybe it was .wsdl, instead of ?wsdl).
Again, sorry for not posting the solution...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I encountered this error and found that it appeared to be due to using a URL that returned an HTTP 302 redirect instead of the WSDL directly.

The URL I was using was in the format `/Service?wsdl`, which redirected to a URL in the format `/Service/wsdl/Service.wsdl`. Once I used the redirect target URL directly, everything worked.

Answer (score 4):

I remember reading that it could be related to the endpoint expecting a trailing '/'. I'm not sure if this valid, but please try it and post here it if works.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error and when I checked the server logs - it was related to http server having encountered an unsupported http method in request. Due to this teh server returns an HTTP response that the SOAP client cannot handle ... hence Unexpected EOF in prolog
Below is a snippet my web-server log for tomcat "localhost.XXXX.log"

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.SecurityConstraint.findUncoveredHttpMethods For security constraints with URL pattern [/services/*] only the HTTP methods [POST GET] are covered. All other methods are uncovered.
```

This gave following error on client side

```
 com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
```

In my case since I was downgrading a secured service to unsecured and my web.xml had following stray entry that was restricting GET and post with a security constraint and I wasnt sending needed security parameters in the request..

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>restricted web services</web-resource-name>
          <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
          <http-method>GET</http-method>
          <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
```

I removed this constraint to get rid of this error :-)

In your case it may not related to security constraint  - but for sure its related to server sending raw http response -  Please check your server/ client configuration and ensure it sends appropriate http request that are liked by http server

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error and when I checked the server logs - it was related to http server having encountered an unsupported http method in request returns an HTTP response that the SOAP client cannot handle ... check your web-server logs

Answer (score 1):

Surely this isn't due to character or format issue.
It's possible that the server didn't return any data, of which the Woodstox (wstx) was trying to parse into XML and failed, which resulted to this error.

Comment: This scenario occurred again in another project and I could confirm it's due to empty data. And when Woodstox tries to parse it, this error message is produced. Proof: error stacktrace always shows this location `at [row,col,system-id]: [1,0`

Answer (score 1):

I had similiar issue and i have resolved with debugging.
When i try to download WSDL in runtime i found that i could not get the WSDL because of the proxy.
Please check that you can access the WSDL in runtime like this code:

```
  try {
      String wsdl = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(new URL("http://YOUR_WSDL_URL"));
      System.out.println("WSDL => "+wsdl);
  } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the imports are missing. Please check routes to your xsd's.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I had to use the full path to the WSDL file to make it works.

Answer (score 0):

My contribution to this error is this:

I don't get this error when I am in debugging mode.

It seems that when the executor of the Java program that queries the WSDL Service (Java in my case) has the time to perform many requests, like in debugging mode, because of when sometimes the programs stops because I put some breakpoints, in this case I don't get this error.

When I run the program in production mode, yes.

But the requests are the same, the WSDL doesn't change, as well ad the endpoints.

It's like a limitation of the web Server, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this when the input XML file had an empty line at the beginning of file.